# .NET 5 Dependencies Error - Console App - Immediately Fails - How to Troubleshoot - System.Private.Uri.dll

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependencies

I'm new to the .NET Core but not .NET. I'm getting an error when launching a console app on someone else's machine and I don't understand how to troubleshoot/resolve. I assume I am missing something or somehow I have messed up some Nuget dependencies.

```
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (dataimport.deps.json) was not found:
package: 'runtimepack.Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64', version: '5.0.14'
path: 'System.Private.Uri.dll'
```

Comment: have you installed https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Private.Uri/

Comment: Oh I thought that was an internal thing that was already part of .NET